# Twitter Oauth Failed due to signature and token

Tags: java, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to crate a application to authenticate from twitter but am getting the following error
:

```
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

Here is my code for app:

```
public class TwitCons {

    String sign_method ="HMAC-SHA1";

    public static String consumer_key ="^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^";
    public static String consumer_secret="^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^";
    String request_uri = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    String oauth_callback="http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitter/getToken";

    String getNonce(){
        Random ran = new Random(); 
        long nonce1 = ran.nextLong(); 

        Long nonce = Math.abs(new Long(nonce1)); 

        return nonce.toString();
    }


    String getTimestamp(){
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();


        return String.valueOf(time/1000);
    }


    String getSignature(String request_uri ,String request_token,String nonce) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String base="oauth_callback=http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitter/getToken&oauth_consumer_key="+consumer_key+"&oauth_nonce="+nonce+"&oauth_signature_method="+sign_method+"&oauth_timestamp="+getTimestamp()+"&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0";

        String baseString="POST&"+URLEncoder.encode(request_uri , "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode(base , "UTF-8");

        String signKey = consumer_secret +"&"+ request_token ;
        System.out.println(signKey +"\n"+baseString);

        try {
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(signKey.getBytes(),"HmacSHA1");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(signingKey.getAlgorithm());
            mac.init(signingKey);
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
            String result = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawHmac));
            System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(result , "UTF-8"));
            return URLEncoder.encode(result , "UTF-8");
            //return result;

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            return "";
        }




    }


}
```

and

```
public class Twitter extends TwitCons{

    public void getRequest() throws IllegalArgumentException, HttpException, IOException
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
        String nonce=getNonce();
        String header = "oauth_callback=\""+URLEncoder.encode(oauth_callback ,"UTF-8")+"\","+
            "oauth_consumer_key=\""+consumer_key +"\","+
            "oauth_nonce=\""+nonce + "\","+
            "oauth_signature=\""+getSignature(request_uri,"",nonce) + "\","+ 
            "oauth_signature_method=\""+sign_method + "\","+
            "oauth_timestamp=\""+getTimestamp() + "\","+
            "oauth_version=\"1.0\""  ;

        post.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+header);
        client.executeMethod(post);

        System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString()+"\n"+post.getRequestHeader("Authorization"));






    }
```

Class has method getRequest for making the twitter request for getting request_token and token_secret

and second class TwitCons have different methods and constants to get request token

Answer (score 0):

In `Twitter.getRequest()`, it seems that your header looks wrong. The value of each parameter has to be surrounded by doubles quotes (`"`) :

```
StringBuilder headerBuilder = new StringBuilder("OAuth ");

headerBuilder.append("oauth_callback=\"").append(oauth_callback).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_consumer_key=\"").append(consumer_key).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_nonce=\"").append(nonce).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_signature=\"").append(getSignature(request_uri,"",nonce)).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_signature_method=\"").append(sign_method).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_timestamp=\"").append(getTimestamp()).append("\", ");
headerBuilder.append("oauth_version=\"1.0\"");

String header = headerBuilder.toString();
```

See the corresponding page in the Twitter API for more details : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

**EDIT** : code fixed because there is not any spaces before commas.

Comment: i have chnages the code and added " ...as you said..but still not working

Comment: After reading how to make the header again, there's no spaces before commas. This is my fault. I edited the code.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You're missing the `oauth_token` in your `String base`. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization for how to get one (if you do not already know this and have not just forgotten putting it in your base string ;)).</strike>

It could be that your signature is calculated wrong as your including `&oauth_token=` in your `base` string, but that key is not part of your request. The [OAuth 1.0 specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor14) just says:

> The Signature Base String is a consistent reproducible concatenation of the request elements into a single string.

Could be worth a try to just remove that part of the string.

**UPDATE:**

You probably have to urlencode your callback URL in the Authorization header, have alphabetical ordering and put the parameters in quotes as @air-dex recommended. Try this:

```
String oauth_callback = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitter/getToken";
String oauth_callback_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(oauth_callback, "UTF-8");
```

then

```
String header = "oauth_callback=\"" + oauth_callback_encoded + "\", " +
            "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumer_key + "\", " +
            "oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", " +
            "oauth_signature=\"" + getSignature(request_uri, "", nonce) + "\", " +
            "oauth_signature_method=\"" + sign_method + "\", " +
            "oauth_timestamp=\"" + getTimestamp() + "\", " +
            "oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
```

and

```
String base = "oauth_consumer_key=" + consumer_key + 
            "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce + 
            "&oauth_signature_method=" + sign_method + 
            "&oauth_timestamp=" + getTimestamp() +
            "&oauth_version=1.0";
```

Comment: Wrong. The `oauth_token` is required for all the authenticated requests but the `POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`. It is logical since you are asking for an OAuth token. ;-)

Comment: Damn it, I confused it with the OAuth2 flow where you first redirect the user and then request the access token ;) I will update the post with another suggestion...

Comment: I updated my answer another time with a new shot on your problem ;)

Comment: Is the code in your question your current code? Because the base string there is still not right... Is your callback entry correct in the Twitter App Settings? Further try [checking your system clock](http://blainegarrett.com/2009/07/14/failed-to-validate-oauth-signature-and-token-on-twitter-oauth-check-your-cloc/)

Comment: @Jan Gerlinger : right for the percent encoding. I saw it reading again how to make this header on the Twitter API documentation.

Comment: There's still a `oauth_callback=http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitter/getToken` and a `&oauth_token=` too much in the `base` string. I also missed the spaces before the commas ;)